# lookup two files and print matched content

Tags: awk, merge, grep

I've two files
f1.txt

```
From,Key,Count
abc.org,hello,5
abc.com,hello world,2
def.com,hi there,1
efg.com,hello world,1
```

f2.txt

```
h1,hello world
h2,hi there
h3,hello
```

I want the output file like below

```
From,Key,Count
abc.org,h3,5
abc.com,h1,2
def.com,h2,1
efg.com,h1,1
```

where the second column of f1.txt is matched against second column of f2.txt and the value is replaced with second column of f2.txt in the output file,
(unique part)

I tried using awk like below:

```
awk -F',' FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} ($2 in a) {print $1,a[$1],$2}' f2 f1
```

But it is giving errors and not working as expected

what shall I modify in the awk command?

---

Update:
@Inian That question is merging the two files based on a common field, I've asked for replacing a field based on a mapping from the second file.

Comment: @Inian That question is merging the two files based on a common field, I've asked for replacing a field based on a mapping from the second file.

Comment: @user2340345: We have these questions all over the site. Do make some efforts to browse through the site before posting new ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help here.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==NR{a[$NF]=$1;next} ($2 in a){$2=a[$2]} 1' f2.txt f1.txt
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}  ##Starting BEGIN section here and setting field separator and output field separator as comma here.
FNR==NR{           ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file named f2.txt is being read.
  a[$NF]=$1;       ##Creating an array named a whose index is $NF and value is $1.
  next}            ##Putting next keyword to skip all further statements as of now.
($2 in a){         ##Checking condition if $2 of Input_file2 named f1.txt is coming in aray a then do following.
  $2=a[$2]}        ##Setting current line $2 as value of array a whose index is $2.
1                  ##Printing current line by 1 here.
' f2.txt f1.txt    ##Mentioning Input_file(s) names here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
From,Key,Count
abc.org,h3,5
abc.com,h1,2
def.com,h2,1
efg.com,h1,1
```

Comment: ++ for obvious way to output the header (which didn't occur to me before breakfast :).

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13, it works perfectly. Can you please explain what is NF here?

Comment: @user2340345, check explanation now and let me know if that helps you `$NF` is last field of any line check `man awk` for more details too.

Comment: Thanks, its well explained :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: do close such questions as duplicates next time. Avoid answering these blatant duplicates, they've been asked time and time before, no use in harvesting reputation from answering these